# Change columns size in Objectlistview

Tags: c#, size, objectlistview

[FastDataListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZmYn.png)

I'm using `ObjectListView` for the first time, this is my first try, not exactly what I want.

I dont know how to change the size of the columns. I trued to use autoresize but it doesnt work.
    FDLVFlashedProduct.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
    FDLVFlashedProduct.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);

```
FDLVFlashedProduct.DataSource = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `DataSource` first, and then call `AutoResizeColumns`.

If you do it the other way around (as you currently have), the control is empty (no columns, no rows) when you're trying to resize to content.